# performseaguewithidentifier

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building an iOS application with a login screen.

I have an initial scene with a "login" button and a "register user" button.

The "login" button advances the user to their profile once their credentials have been matched and the "register user" button pulls down a scene (through a modal seague) to register user. I am using the performseaguewithidentfier method for the "login" button authentication(the user can't advance to the next page until the username and password hava been matched). The problem is the button for the "create user" will not work also. Is there a way to only use the performseaguewithidentifier for one of the buttons (the "Login" button).

I've been looking for a relevant answer but nothing applies! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not understanding the question: If you have two buttons that ultimately lead you to two different scenes, then you just have two segues, right? One for when the login is successful which takes you to the profile screen, one for the register scene, which leads you through the process of registering. So you have two buttons, login with what sounds like an `IBAction` that logs you on and then performs the segue to the profile, and another button which is just the segue to the register scene. What precisely is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can have different segues for every button and do various things before performing segue, depending on which segue was invoked, with:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

You should probably read these:

[UIStoryboardSegue Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just give each Segue in your storyboard an identifier. Then in your code, you can call each segue like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueIdentifierName"]) { 
        //do something with seque 
    }
}
```

Comment: okay I will try that. What exactly does the prepareForSeague do?

Comment: Notifies the view controller that a segue is about to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Tag property of the button i.e. button.tag = 0 or any number. 
Then when you segue,  you just compare the tag values using if - else construct. 
Hope this helps.